# Razor Pages and Json

Tags: json, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developing an application that consults a Web API from an affiliate website, gets data in json format and I want to simply present this data in a page.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string urljson)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var resultado = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(urljson);

    Produto.Rootobject Produtos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Produto.Rootobject>(resultado);

    return RedirectToPage("ListaSugestoes", Produtos);
}
```

The code I added in the page I want the results to appear is:

```
using Buyit.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Buyit.Pages
{
    public class ListaSugestoesModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly Produto.Rootobject _jsonProdutos;

        public ListaSugestoesModel(Produto.Rootobject jsonProdutos)
        {
            _jsonProdutos = jsonProdutos;
        }

        public JsonResult OnGetProdutos()
        {
            return new JsonResult(_jsonProdutos);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it done right? I had it work using a Controller, but I am trying to learn Razor Pages and want to know if that's possible to implement using it. Tks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For clarification, are both snippets razor pages?

Comment: Thanks!! Yes, one is a form that according to what it's filled by the user, when she presses submit, it generates  a URL to the third party API, that then returns the result in json. Thus part is working fine. The problem is to send this result to render another page.

Comment: Send the generated url to the other page, have it down load the data and display.

Comment: Have you reviewed the following Reference [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Sorry for being so noon, how do I do that?

Comment: Yes, I did. Maybe I looked the wrong way. I haven't thought about downloading the URL. I will look again. I thought the solution would be something close to using a Controller, as from a coding standpoint.

Comment: It is similar to using a controller. models were never passed via redirects.well maybe temp data but that was a specific edge case.

Comment: Maybe I should just add a controller then, right? I don't need the CRUD capabilities of the Razor Pages for this app anyway.